# How to add Line Break?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

To summarize: I have different kind of category:

- Letter1: Math and physics
- Letter2  Math and Music
- Letter3: Physic and Sport
- Letter4: Sport and Music

The result on my excel file:

| Title | Math | Physic | Sport | Music | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | X | X |  | X | Letter1, Letter2 |
| Kate | X | X |  |  | Letter1 |
| Steven |  |  | X | X | Letter4 |
| Bart | X | X | X | X | Letter1,LEtter 2,LEtter3,LEtter4 |

I try to add a Line Break/Carriage Return on my formula.

The formula show different kind of result in one cellule ... Where should I place the CHAR(10) (Line Break/CR)?

```
=CONCAT(IF(A1="o","Letter1 ","CHAR(10)"),IF(B1="o","Letter2 ",""),IF(C1="o","Letter3 ",""),IF(D1="o","Letter3",""))
```

Thanks,

S.

Comment: Did you set the cell format to `Wrap Text`?

Comment: Yes but all the info are show in one line .... example: Letter1, Letter2, Letter3

Comment: Your line feed comes only if the first `IF()` statement is false. How should it look?

Comment: I edited the question, is that answer?

Comment: Ok. What version of Excel do you have? Do you have Office 365?

Comment: Yes, O365 version

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", "&CHAR(10), 1,IF(AND(B2="x",C2="x"),"Letter1",""),IF(AND(B2="x",E2="x"),"Letter2",""), IF(AND(C2="x",D2="x"),"Letter3",""), IF(AND(D2="x",E2="x"),"Letter4",""))
```